# How to remove global phase from matrices

Tags: matrix, group-theory

I have a list of 3 by 3 complex matrices. I would like to remove the matrices that are similar up to a global phase factor.
For instance, I have $ M, \mathrm e^{\mathrm  i2\pi/3}M $ and $ \mathrm e^{-\mathrm  i2\pi/3}M $ with $ M $ some matrix. I would like to keep only one of them in the resulting list. How can I implement that?

Behind this question, I have a group $ G $ of matrices defined as a list and I would like to have the list of matrices in the quotient group $ G/U(1) $

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[#/Normalize@#[[1,1]]&]@list` should do the trick. Essentially, this compares a canonicalized form of the matrices, where the first entry is positive & real.

Comment: Thinking about it, you'll have to handle the case where the first entry is `0` somehow - something like `DeleteDuplicatesBy[#/Normalize@FirstCase[Flatten@#,Except[0|0.],1]&]` should probably work

Comment: I actually did something similar, but I need to loop over the matrix positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group of matrices; by definition these are invertible, so their determinant is non-zero. For example, we will take

```
Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 3}], 5]
Det /@ %
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 1 & 7 \\
 9 & 3 & 9 \\
 10 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 3 & 6 & 2 \\
 7 & 8 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 7 & 1 & 3 \\
 9 & 3 & 8 \\
 2 & 2 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 8 & 3 & 10 \\
 4 & 5 & 5 \\
 8 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 3 & 8 \\
 6 & 3 & 7 \\
 2 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
-48, -60, 12, -112, 87
$$
and

```
G = Sequence @@ Table[# Exp[2 π I j/3], {j, 0, 2}] & /@ %%;
```

The quotient group $G/U(1)$ (well, in this case, $G/\mathbb Z_3$) can be obtained as follows:

```
Gather[G, 
       Assuming[θ ∈ Reals, 
       Reduce[#1.Inverse[#2] == Exp[2 π I θ] IdentityMatrix[3]] =!= False
       ] &
      ]
```

If OP only wants one representative for each orbit, they can use `First /@ %`.

The method is not particularly efficient, but hopefully it is readable and clear. If OP has matrices that are much larger, then an alternative method might be necessary.

Comment: thank you. I still have to learn how the Mathematica command works

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`MatrixRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank) of pairs of flattened matrices. For example:

```
scaledQ[m1_, m2_] := MatrixRank[{Flatten @ m1, Flatten @ m2}] == 1
```

An example matrix:

```
SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[10, {3,3}]
```

> {{1, 4, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 6, 0}}

Check trivial example:

```
scaledQ[m, Exp[Pi I/3] m]
```

> True

A more complicated example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
matrices = RandomInteger[10, {5, 3, 3}];
G = Join[matrices, Exp[2 Pi I/3] matrices, Exp[4 Pi I/3] matrices];
```

There are 15 matrices in `G`:

```
Length @ G
```

> 15

There should only be 5 different matrices after removing scaled versions:

```
DeleteDuplicates[G, scaledQ] //Length
```

> 5